# index out of range raises in random function

Tags: python

I have this function which simply opens a text files and read lines:

```
def select_word(model):
    lines = model.read().splitlines()
    selectedline = random.choice(lines)
    return [selectedline.split(":")[0],selectedline.split(":")[1]]
```

when I call this function for just one, there is no problem. But when I call it more than once:

```
print select_word(a)
print select_word(a)
print select_word(a)
print select_word(a)
print select_word(a)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordselect.py", line 58, in <module>
    print select_word("noun")   
  File "wordselect.py", line 19, in select_word
    selectedline = random.choice(lines)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the problem with that function?

Comment: Your function does not open any file..

Comment: no it opens, I defined this model thing in another place. It works with one call

Comment: You should be opening your file inside your function...So again...your function does not open any file !

Comment: What is `a` in `print select_word(a)` BTW ?

Comment: well that's confidential...

Comment: Well then...Good luck with it...

Comment: Functions have implied contracts: "I take a file-like object, read to end-of-file and return a random line. I raise an error for empty lines and empty files". Its not inherently a bug - it would be perfectly rational to write a function like this and expect the caller to rewind the file pointer as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File handles operate like generators. Once you have read a file, you have reached the end of stream.

```
model.seek(0) # bring cursor to start of file after reading, at 2nd line of the function
```

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: I open file in different python file and imported this one I think that causes the problem right?

Comment: actually it fixed the problem but I have no clue how

Comment: If you are reading a book and you reach the final page, is there anything left to read? No that's it. It's the end of the line. If you want to keep reading, you need to start at the beginning by going to the front. Same thing in code.

Answer (score 2):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) raises `IndexError` if you pass it an empty sequence. This happens when you call [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) on a file object the second time (you can only do it once, subsequent calls will return an empty string).

To fix the function, you could read the file once then pass the lines to the function, e.g.:

```
lines = list(model)

def select_word(lines):    
    selectedline = random.choice(lines)
    return selectedline.split(":", 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def select_word(model):
    with open(model, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    selectedline = random.choice(lines)
    return [selectedline.split(":")[0],selectedline.split(":")[1]]

result = select_word('example.txt')
print result
```

I did this and didnt get a problem.
just make sure that in the file you are opening you have something like.

```
Line: 1
Line: 2
```